# How to get a nice approximation of $f(N,s)=\sum_{k=0}^{N}{N \choose k}{k \choose s-k+N}$ when $N>>1$ and $|s|<<N$?

Tags: binomial-coefficients, approximation, expectation

I need to approximate the above sum in order to calculate $\mathbb{E}(s^2)$, which is the expectation value determined by the probability density function $f$ and the position $s$. Any idea?